# YII url management working besides urls with id's

Tags: php, url, yii, seo, yii-url-manager

I've enabled url management within my YII project.
Most of the links are working, however i have a few links which have an id which is obtained from the database, these links aren't working.

localhost/project/site/contact <-- This link is working

localhost/project/site/page&view=contentpage&id=1 <-- This one isn't.

How can i get this link to behave as a seo-friendly url?

These are my current rules within the urlmanager in my main.php file.

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'showScriptName'=>false,
                    'caseSensitive'=>false, 
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

        ),
             ),
```

Thank you so much already!

Edit- I have now changed the url to have a ? instead of a &.
The link is now working, but how do I make it seo-friendly, any idea's? Thanks! :)

Comment: The 2nd one shouldn't work as it cannot determine controller and achtion. The first '&' should be a '?'. Does that solve anything? (localhost/project/site/page?view=contentpage&id=1)

Comment: try `localhost/project/site/page/1?view=contentpage`

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies. The link is indeed working now! Thanks for your replies. However it isn't really seo-friendly, any idea on what rule I should create to make those links seo friendly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rule: `'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>'`,

url:`localhost/project/site/page/1/view/contentpage`

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply. I have just added the rule '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>', but the url is still like this :'page?view=contentpage&id=1' any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: try this: `$this->createUrl('site/page', array('id'=>1, 'view'=>'contentpage'))`

Comment: Where do I have to put that line exactly? Tried a few places but didn't work yet.

Comment: For example in HTML for create link:
`<a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('site/page', array('id'=>1, 'view'=>'contentpage')) ?>">linkContent</a>`
and you get:
`<a href="localhost/project/site/page/1/view/contentpage">linkContent</a>`

Comment: The link works! We're using a widget (Cmenu) to generate a menu in the upper right corner aswell. Is it possible to do this in a array aswell? following line : `array('label'=>Yii::t('app','algemeen.test'), 'url'=>array('site/page?view=contentpage&id=1'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),`
p.s. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: `array('label'=>Yii::t('app','algemeen.test'), 'url'=>array('site/page', 'page'=>'1', 'view'=>'content'))`